# Unit testing a BehaviorSubject in a service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs

I'm working on a toy project to learn unit testing in Angular (replaced Karma with Jest). I've seen similar questions but all of them handle subscriptions differently, so I wasn't able to get the exact answer to work for me.

TL;DR: I'm trying to test a BehaviorSubject, but rather than the value I'm expecting, it's sending it's initial value to me. I understand the ordering of the subscription in the test matters, but I couldn't figure the proper ordering yet.

I have a BehaviorSubject in a service:

```
export class SomeService {
  // ...
  remainingSeconds: number;

  private _seconds: Subject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(RegularTimerSeconds.WORK_TIME);
  public readonly seconds$: Observable<number> = this._seconds.asObservable();

  setTimer(seconds: number) {
    this.remainingSeconds = seconds;
    this._seconds.next(this.remainingSeconds);
  }

  // ...
}
```

and a listener on a component, which subscribes to the Observable using the async pipe in the template

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  // ...
  remainingSeconds$ = this.timer.seconds$.pipe(tap(seconds => console.log(`remainingSeconds$: ${seconds}`)));

  constructor(public timer: TimerService) {}
}
```

Subscription happens in the template as follows

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{
  remainingSeconds: remainingSeconds$ | async,
  currentState: currentState$ | async,
  informationText: informationText$ | async,
  doneCounter: doneCounter$ | async
} as data">
  <!-- ... -->
  <div class="regular-timer-container" *ngIf="data.remainingSeconds !== undefined">
    <p>Remaining seconds: {{ data.remainingSeconds }}</p>  
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

I would like to test that when the `setTimer` function in the service is called, the remainingSeconds$ observable in the component also gets the correct value. Especially, if the "remainingSeconds" value in the service is undefined, I'd like to make sure that the remainingSeconds$ observable gets the updated undefined value, and thus the appropriate UI element is hidden.

The problem I'm having with the test (for which the code is below) is that when I call `service.setTimer(undefined)` from the component, I'm getting the initial value of the BehaviorSubject rather than the `undefined` value I wanted (which makes the test useless).

```
it(`shouldn't render the timer component if the seconds value is unset`, async(() => {
  component.remainingSeconds$
    .subscribe(
      seconds => {
        expect(seconds).toEqual(undefined);

        fixture.detectChanges();

        const timerContainerDom: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement;
        const regularTimerComponent = timerContainerDom.query(By.directive(AppComponent));

        expect(regularTimerComponent).toBeFalsy();
      }
    );

  timerService.setTimer(undefined);
}));
```

I'm adding [a stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5wvhcv), but sadly I couldn't run npm test on there. Hopefully it'll give some basic idea as to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Have you tried `component.remainingSeconds$.pipe(skip(1)).subscribe(...)` ?

Comment: @AndreiGătej thank you for your response - I hadn't used that. Theoretically and practically it works fine, since it skips the initial value of the BehaviorSubject, which solves my problem. In the meantime, I was wondering if testing BehaviorSubjects has a general "go-to good practice" about them. If you can post this as an answer, I'll select it as the good one. :)

Comment: I'm not aware of a 'one-size-fits-all' solution, but what I'd do in your case is to separate the tasks, asking myself: what am I trying to test? For example, if you want to test that the **observable** emits the right values after some events, you might want to use marble testing for this. If you want to test if some elements correctly appear in the DOM, I wouldn't factor in the real source of events(e.g a `Subject`), but a mocked observable, that will simply emit some values, allowing me to focus on the view testing.

Comment: I've added the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could quickly solve this with:

```js
component.remainingSeconds$.pipe(skip(1)).subscribe(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [
          AppComponent
        ],
        providers: [
          TimerService
        ]
      }).compileComponents();
```

and remove TestBed.inject

Comment: Thanks for answering :) in the test I'm using an instance of timerService, though. Where and how would you suggest I instantiate it?

Comment: no need to instantiate it, just add it in providers array. then from testbed.get, get the instance of service.

Comment: Actually the reason I was using .inject() was because [get() is deprecated](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/TestBed)